# Что значит флаги -it в docker run?

Tags: docker

Я изучаю докер и не понимаю, что за флаги `-i` и `-t`. Везде непонятно пишут или не yделяют особого внимания.

Comment: Это два отдельных флага `-i` и `-t`, и про оба конечно есть документация https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Ключ -i == --interactive. Ключ -t == --tty

Comment: @Pak Uula Что значит интерактивный? Что такое tty?

Comment: @Egork.vorobiev ответ на ваш вопрос есть по ссылке выше, не поленитесь перейти прочесть пару строк

Comment: @Egork.vorobiev интерактивный - значит контейнер не в фоне будет запущен, а терминал откроется как бы внутри контейнера, и вы сможете выполнить нужные команды.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-i` или `--interactive` означает, что запускаемый контейнер получает стандартный поток ввода из хоста и перенаправляет его в запущенное приложение. По-умолчанию контейнеры стартуют изолированно, и `/dev/stdin` запущенного приложения не имеет связи с внешним миром.

`-t` или `--tty` означает, что докер создаёт для запущенного приложения псевдотерминал. Это позволяет приложению выводить цветной текст, перемещать курсор (точку вывода) по экрану консоли и много чего ещё.

**ПРИМЕР**

Попробуем запускать шелл `/bin/sh` с разными комбинациями `-it`.

**`-i -t`**

```bash
docker run --rm -i -t alpine /bin/sh
```

В консоли запустится шелл и напечатает промт `/ #`

Напишите команду `ls` и нажмите ввод.

Получится что-то такое:

```
bin    dev    etc    home   lib    media  mnt    opt    proc   root   run    sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
```

Каталоги выведены в одну строку и раскрашены синим цветом.

**`-t`**

Запустите без `-i`:

```
docker run --rm -t alpine /bin/sh
```

Контейнер запустится, шелл напечатает промт `/ #`

Попробуйте запустить команду `ls`: напечатайте `ls` и нажмите ввод. И что? И ничего. Без флага `-i` процесс из контейнера не видит, что вы печатаете в консоли. Контейнер создаст для `/bin/sh` стандартный поток ввода, но этот поток никак не связан с консолью, откуда вы контейнер запустили.

**`-i`**

Запустим без `-t`:

```
docker run --rm -i alpine /bin/sh
```

Процесс запустится, но промт не напечатает. Просто пустая строка.

Напечатайте команду `ls` и нажмите ввод. Благодаря флагу `-i` шелл увидит эту команду и обработает её, выдав список каталогов на стандартный вывод.

```
bin
dev
...
var
```

Вывод в колонку и без цвета. Причина - без терминала шелл не может передвигать курсор в строке, чтобы печатать каталоги в одной строке, и не может  управлять цветом. Этим же объясняется отсуствие промта `/ #`  - без терминала нет редактирования строки, шелл принимает на вход команды и выдаёт их результат на выход.

**без всего**

```
docker run --rm alpine /bin/sh
```

Контейнер запустится и тут же завершится. У шелла нет стандартного ввода, нет терминала, поэтому он автоматически завершается.