# Docker. Консольный ввод данных в контейнере

Tags: docker

Навскидку не найду способа, подключившись к контейнеру, ввести с клавиатуры данные по консольному запросу программы, работающей в контейнере.
Доступен лог контейнера, где есть вывод текста программой и приглашения ввести данные. Но, нет возможности их ввести. В терминале bash диалог с программой отсутствует.
Как всё-таки выйти в режим запросов программы и ввести данные через консоль?

Comment: `docker exec -it <container_name> <sh|bash>` [Документация по docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/exec/)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561083/Что-значит-флаги-it-в-docker-run